# How to check/uncheck 3 secondary checkboxes according to 1 principal checkbox (19times)?

Tags: javascript, dom, checkbox

I have 19 cards of 4 checkboxes: 1 main checkbox (date) and 3 secondary checkboxes (options for that date). I would like the 3 secondary options to be checked when the main one is checked and conversely that they are unchecked when the main one is unchecked. 
I would like to use a single function for all 19 cards. However, checkboxes have different ids.

When I click on a main checkbox
I get the id from the main checkbox.
I retrieve the number contained in the id.
I apply it to three values to create the id of 3 secondary checkboxes.
If the main checkbox is checked:
I check the secondary checkboxes.
If the main checkbox is unchecked:
I uncheck the secondary checkboxes.

I tried with "onclick" and "onchange".

```js
function Autocheck(id) {

  var clicked_id = id;
  var StgNbr = clicked_id.substr(4);

  var diner = "Dîner" + StgNbr;
  var souper = "Souper" + StgNbr;
  var logement = "Logement" + StgNbr;

  if (clicked_id.checked = true) {
    alert('je suis coché');
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName('presence');
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

      if (items[i].id == diner)
        items[i].checked = true;
      if (items[i].id == souper)
        items[i].checked = true;
      if (items[i].id == logement)
        items[i].checked = true;
    }



  } else {
    alert('je suis décoché');
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName('presence');
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

      if (items[i].id == diner)
        items[i].checked = false;
      if (items[i].id == souper)
        items[i].checked = false;
      if (items[i].id == logement)
        items[i].checked = false;
    }

  }

}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <div class="card">
      <label for="date1"><div class="card-media"><input type="checkbox" id="date1" class="date presence" name="Dates" onclick="Autocheck(this.id)">&nbsp; &nbsp;Mardi 23/07</div></label>
      <div class="card-details">
        <input type="checkbox" class="presence" name="Dîner" id="Dîner1">
        <label for="Dîner1">&nbsp; &nbsp;Dîner</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="presence" name="Souper" id="Souper1">
        <label for="Souper">&nbsp; &nbsp;Souper</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="presence" name="Logement" id="Logement1">
        <label for="Logement">&nbsp; &nbsp;Logement</label><br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <div class="card">
      <label for="date2"><div class="card-media"><input type="checkbox" id="date2" class="date presence" name="Dates" onchange="Autocheck(this.id)">&nbsp; &nbsp;Mercredi 24/07</div></label>
      <div class="card-details">
        <input type="checkbox" class="presence" name="Dîner" id="Dîner2">
        <label for="Dîner2">&nbsp; &nbsp;Dîner</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="presence" name="Souper" id="Souper2">
        <label for="Souper2">&nbsp; &nbsp;Souper</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="presence" name="Logement" id="Logement2">
        <label for="Logement2">&nbsp; &nbsp;Logement</label><br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My secondary checkboxes are well cheched but they don't uncheck.
Also : my 'test' alert is always saying that the principal checkbox is checked even if I uncheck it.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `if(clicked_id.checked = true)` assigns `true` to `clicked_id.checked`. Just do `if(clicked_id.checked)`.

Comment: I assume all related check boxes have a distinct common ancestor, like `.card` in your example?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Every four checkboxes are in a div "card".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a click listener and on click of main checkbox we check/uncheck child check boxes. Is this what you are looking for?

```js
const getParentCard = (e, classToMatch) => {
  while( e.classList.contains(classToMatch) === false) 
  {
    e = e.parentNode;
  }
  return e;
};
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if(e.target.matches('input.date')){  
    getParentCard(e.target,'card').querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach(chk => {
      chk.checked = e.target.checked;
    });
  }
  
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <div class="card">
      <label for="date1">
        <div class="card-media">
          <input type="checkbox" id="date1" class="date presence" name="Dates">&nbsp; &nbsp;Mardi 23/07
         </div>
       </label>
      <div class="card-details">
        <input type="checkbox" class="presence" name="Dîner" id="Dîner1">
        <label for="Dîner1">&nbsp; &nbsp;Dîner</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="presence" name="Souper" id="Souper1">
        <label for="Souper">&nbsp; &nbsp;Souper</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="presence" name="Logement" id="Logement1">
        <label for="Logement">&nbsp; &nbsp;Logement</label><br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <div class="card">
      <label for="date2"><div class="card-media"><input type="checkbox" id="date2" class="date presence" name="Dates">&nbsp; &nbsp;Mercredi 24/07</div></label>
      <div class="card-details">
        <input type="checkbox" class="presence" name="Dîner" id="Dîner2">
        <label for="Dîner2">&nbsp; &nbsp;Dîner</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="presence" name="Souper" id="Souper2">
        <label for="Souper2">&nbsp; &nbsp;Souper</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="presence" name="Logement" id="Logement2">
        <label for="Logement2">&nbsp; &nbsp;Logement</label><br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two main problems in your code:

```
if (clicked_id.checked = true) {
```

performs an assignment instead of a comparison but more importantly, `clicked_id` is a **string** and string values don't have a `checked` property. You'd have to access the `checked` property of the actual element , by either passing the element as argument to the function (preferred) or do

```
var element = document.getElementById(clicked_id);
//...
if (element.checked) {
  // ...
}
```

---

Having said that, a more flexible approach that works with any number of check boxes without having to update the code is as follows:

- Find closest common ancestor
- Find all check boxes within that ancestor

Example:

```
function Autocheck(element) {
  var ancestor = element.closest('.card');
  if (ancestor) {
    Array.from(ancestor.querySelectorAll('.presence')).forEach(function(input) {
      input.checked = element.checked;
    });
  }
}
```

and use it as

```
<input type="checkbox" id="date1" class="date presence" name="Dates" onclick="Autocheck(this)">
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. I saw that element.closest isn't supported on IE and Edge. :/

Comment: It should be supported on edge at least. MDN has a polyfill you can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest